write_dataset() function creates thousands of tiny Parquet files within partition
I am building a Parquet dataset partitioned along two columns. It is built directly from 30.000 txt files (100k lines each) which are too large to load into memory at once. I proceed as follows:
mydata <- open_dataset(
          sources = paste0(path_chunks,chunk_list), # character vector with paths to my 30k .txt files
          format = "text",
          parse_options = parse_opts,               # just some options like the separator etc
          schema = myschema,                        # defines my column types using arrow::schema()
          skip_rows = 0)

I write the dataset as follows:
write_dataset(dataset = mydata,
              path = path_parquet,                  # path to my parquet datasystem
              format = "parquet",
              partitioning = 
              c("country", "type"),                 # my partition variables
              compression = "snappy",
              use_dictionary = TRUE, 
              write_statistics = TRUE,
              min_rows_per_group = 5000000,         # memory usage, has nothing to do with file size
              existing_data_behavior = "delete_matching")

It all works, I'm getting a parquet dataset which I can query based on my subsets and it is amazingly fast. One thing that confuses me though is that within one subset (like "country == UK" and "type == A") I can have thousands of Parquet files. The first one is large (for some several gigabyte), all the others are tiny, usually <100 kilobytes. It looks to me as if after initially collecting something, there is a new Parquet file created every time a new chunk of my 30k chunks has that subset combination. My original data is mostly ordered by country but not perfectly so this is possible. Since arrow recommends much larger parquet files and less of them I would like to have fewer larger files. How can I enforce this in the construction of the parquet filesystem? The min/max row arguments don't seem to apply because (a) I don't know how many rows of a subset I will have so I don't want to set a minimum (they can be tiny) and (b) setting a maximum does not seem to be the issue because I'm getting thousands of tiny files.
ps.: If someone knows the appropriate arrow tag for this question please add, I'm not finding it.

Have you tried write_parquet? It has different parameters

I see, thanks. I can give it a run but I don't see why that would help from the help file: chunk_size would need to know the entire data beforehand but I'm working from many text files, not one... Maybe ex post collection is better?

This situation might also fit better as an issue on their github
